# Extend Array using John Resig Extend

Tags: javascript

I have been using John Resig's simple inheritance scheme in my project.
http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Basically, I have an object that I want to use as an array, but with some more properties.

I'm aware that there are other ways to extend Array, however I have been using this extend method throughout my code, so I would like it to be consistent.

I would like something like this, it's very awkward though:

```
var Array2 = Class.extend(Array);
var Foo = Array2.extend(
{
  init : function() {
  }
});
```

EDIT: One of the major problems is that the 'length' property is not properly updated when you add something via index. I.e

```
var x = new Foo(); 
x[0] = "test";
alert(x.length) //0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not actual code but, something of this kind might help:

```
var Array2 = Class.extend(Array);
var Foo = Array2.extend(
{
  init : function() {
    return Array.prototype.push.apply(this,arguments);
  }
});
```

Hope it helps you moving ahead